# Why don't we compute a p-value for p-value being below 0.05?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

For the purpose of this post, accept that there is some critical threshold below which a finding is declared to be statistically significant.

The *p*-value is a statistic because it is a function of the data.

Statistics are random variables. We can put confidence intervals around statistics.

Why don't we put confidence intervals around *p*-values? Or, equivalently, why don't we test the hypothesis that the observed *p*-value is below 0.05, say?

One answer could be that it would be hard to calculate analytically, but bootstrapping could solve that issue.

Comment: p-value is a characteristic of a given sample, not an estimate of something in the population to be able to bear some error. So p-value is an exact number, not an interval. p-value is interval only in Monte Carlo testing - because in such a testing not full information from the sample is used to compute p.

Comment: The *p*-value depends on the null hypothesis in addition to the data, whereas the data do not depend on the null hypothesis.

Comment: Very relevant thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254595 - see discussions in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, you might want to read:
[The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant](http://jonathanrenshon.com/Teaching/NPS/ResearchDesign/Gelman-Significance.pdf)

Comment: This is a bare link and does not describe the bare connection to the question. Though it is good reading.

Comment: I generally agree that one-sentence answers are bad, but that's all I have. I can't explain it myself, but know of a paper by a famous statistician who seems to address the point.

Comment: @Wayne, I'm aware of the paper, thanks. But Gelman and Stern are arguing that estimates of a mean, say, between two samples may not be statistically different even though one of the estimates is significant while the other is not. I'm looking at a different issue: Why no confidence intervals around a p-value for a particular sample?